# Must I provide ProductId to query product details with Google play in-app purchase system in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

I know I can use the following code to query in-app products detail by providing ProductId.

At present, I hope to query all  in-app products  details,  must I provide all ProductId ?

```
 fun queryProductDetails() {
        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        val productList = mutableListOf<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product>()
        for (product in LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) {

            productList.add(
                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(product)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build()
            )
        }

        params.setProductList(productList).let { productDetailsParams ->
            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(productDetailsParams.build(), mOnProductDetailsResponse)
        }
    }


  private val LIST_OF_PRODUCTS = listOf(BASIC_SUB, PREMIUM_SUB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to query all in-app products without specifying their `productId`s and `type` (`BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP` or `BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS`).

If some of the `productId`s don't exist or are provided with the wrong `type`, you won't receive an error but simply a returned list containing only those product details that match both criteria.

E.g. if `BASIC_SUB` and `PREMIUM_SUB` from the question are active subscriptions, then you'll receive an empty list when querying with `ProductType.INAPP` and a list of 2 product details when querying with `ProductType.SUBS`.